# How to call module with object Parameter in main file Index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I need to call module from main index.js File

***Here is my module***

```
const request = require('./rq.js');
const callback = require('./callback.js')

const url = `https://localhost.3000/${id}`;


request(url, callback)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})


module.exports = page; //Tell me how to export all code from module
```

So here is my index.js file

```
const Methods = {
  page: require('./page.js'),
}


module.exports = //What i need to code here?
```

File from what i give a call a module :

```
const main = require('./index.js');

main.page({id: 'id'})

.then(console.log);
```

**So what I should change to call page.js file like that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes to page.js since in your main file you expect a promise to be returned.

```
const request = require('./rq.js');
const callback = require('./callback.js')

function page({id}) {
    const url = `https://localhost.3000/${id}`;
    return request(url, callback)
}

module.exports = {page: page} //Tell me how to export all code from module
```

Make the following changes to Mehods.js

```
const Methods = {
  page: require('./page.js').page,
}


module.exports = Methods;
```

Check if this works.

Comment: but how about ${id} ?

Comment: @AlbertJovinskyi updated the code now check. Sorry my bad.